# Is there a phrase like "preaching to the choir" but with the opposite meaning?

Tags: phrases, expressions, idioms

"Preaching to the choir" means you're making a point to a group of people who all already agree with you.

Is there a similar phrase, meaning you're making a point/argument to a group of people who would never listen to you?

For example, heading to a vegan convention to tell everyone about how great it is to eat meat.

Comment: fall on deaf ears.
https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/fall-on-deaf-ears

Comment: You are "barking up the wrong tree"

Comment: Casting pearls before swine.